# Как работать в cпринге с JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-jpa

Хочу разобраться в Spring JPA и для этого читаю книгу Spring in Action. По ходу изложения пытаюсь написать небольшой проект. Вот так написан `persistence.xml`:

```xml
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="UserPU">
        <class>main.domain.User</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="toplink.jdbc.Driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
            <property name="toplink.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql:test"/>
            <property name="toplink.jdbc.user" value="postgres"/>
            <property name="toplink.jdbc.password" value="postgres"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Конфиг приложения:

```java
package main.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean;

@Configuration
public class JpaConfig {
    @Bean
    public LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean() {
        LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean emfb = new LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        emfb.setPersistenceUnitName("UserPU");
        return emfb;
    }
}
```

Класс сущности:

```java
package main.domain;

public class User {
}
```

Я не могу разметить его аннотациями, потому что по какой-то причине пакет `javax.persistence` недоступен.

Главный класс:

```java
package main;

import main.config.JpaConfig;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx =
                new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(JpaConfig.class);
    }
}
```

У меня это все не работает. При запуске приложения я получаю ошибку:

```
Dec 07, 2018 1:37:46 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext refresh
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactoryBean' defined in main.config.JpaConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactoryBean' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/PersistenceException
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactoryBean' defined in main.config.JpaConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactoryBean' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/PersistenceException
    at org.springf
```

Зависимости настроены так:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
         http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>main</groupId>
    <artifactId>main</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Почему ничего не работает? Каких зависимостей не хватает, чтобы правильно использовать JPA и писать не на спринг буте?

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы пакет `javax.persistence` был доступен, нужно добавить в конфигурацию проекта `maven` какого-либо *persistence-провайдера*, например `hibernate`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.7.Final</version>
</dependency>
```